# Detect right click on toolstrip button

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip, toolstripitem

I have a toolstrip with a context menu and a toolstrip button in it with a click event.
Initially I tried to assign the context menu to the button itself, but couldn't find a context menu in its property.
So I assigned the context menu to the toolstrip.
Now whenever I right click the button for the context menu to appear, the button click event is triggered.
I want to check which mouse button is clicked, so I tired to cast event args to mouseeventargs:

```
if (((MouseEventArgs)e).Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
```

but I got an exception that I can't do this cast.
Can I either assign context menu to the button or detect which mouse button is clicked?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the `MouseDown` event of the `ToolStripButton` like this:

```
private void toolStripButton1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
   if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right){
      //...
   }
}
```

Comment: @Jerry Mark this as an answer to help future users of SO.

Comment: Sure I will. When I tried I got a message that I have to wait 10 minutes.