# ToolStrip Controls MouseClick?

Tags: c#, right-click, mouseclick-event, toolstrip

I want to check if the user did right click on a button which is in a toolStrip, but there's no MouseClick event for each control.

example of right clicking:

```
    private void tabControl1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            Point pt = tabControl1.PointToScreen(e.Location);
            tabContxt.Show(pt);
        }
    }
```

i want to do the same for the button in the toolStrip, if you can help me :). Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544505/detect-right-click-on-toolstrip-button


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544505/detect-right-click-on-toolstrip-button

Comment: It seems that i didn't search very well, but i did search at first :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Mouse_Down`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

```
private void toolStripButton1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void tabControl1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var zz = ((MouseEventArgs)e).Button;

    if (zz == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        Point pt = tabControl1.PointToScreen(e.Location);
        tabContxt.Show(pt);
    }
}
```